Archiving old documents in SharePoint Server 2019 on prem
In the company I work for, I have a SharePoint Server 2019 on prem Farm. There are more than 40 site collections and each site collection content database is growing fast due to employees upload many documents everyday. Microsoft recommends that all SharePoint content databases should not exceed 200gb. So I'm looking for a solution to archive the old files in each document library of every site collections that haven't been updated for 3 years. I'm planning to move them to another sperate location like a new SharePoint Server for archiving or a local drive. The idea of separating the archived documents from the main SharePoint Server is to keep all site collection databases size in the SQL as recommended by Microsoft.
So, Should I build a new SharePoint Server for archiving the old documents or just move the old documents to a storage like a local drive?
Can I use PowerShell or C# console app to move the old documents containing their metadata like DateUpdated?
Any ideas?
